# rsyslog not writing log file after restart

Tags: redhat, syslog, rsyslog

First off, thanks for spending the time to have a look at this issue, its much appreciated.

I've had the attached rsyslog.conf configuration running for sometime now until today when I had to restart rsyslog as a disk was getting full. The result is that rsyslog is now logging to a new location (upated in .conf file) with all the previous permissions (currently root|root rw to be testing safe).

The issue I'm facing is that no matter what I try, rsyslog does not output a file. I've run a tcpdump and I'm still receiving data. The matching criteria (host IP address) shouldn't have changes and the config hasn't changed either.

Any help, particularly debug commands I can run would be greatly appreciated. I would rather learn something new (like rsyslog) than uninstall it and just use syslog-ng instead...
Here is the config:

```
    ### Modules
$ModLoad imtcp
$ModLoad imudp
$ModLoad imuxsock       # provides support for local system logging (e.g. via logger command)
$ModLoad imklog         # provides kernel logging support (previously done by rklogd)

### Set log file permissions
$FileOwner root
$FileGroup root
$FileCreateMode 0777
$DirCreateMode 0777
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser root
$PrivDropToGroup root

### Listeners
# bind ruleset to tcp listener
$InputTCPServerBindRuleset remote
# and activate it:
$InputTCPServerRun 514

$InputUDPServerBindRuleset remote
$UDPServerRun 514

### Templates
#Format the message correctly
$template MsgFormat,"%msg%\n"

# log every host in its own directory

##$template TESTLOG,"/opt/rsyslog/var/log/test.log"

### Rulesets
# Local Logging
# N/A None required at this point in time
#
# Remote Logging
$RuleSet remote

#---MY MATCHING RULE---#

if ($fromhost-ip == "192.168.1.1") then ?TESTLOG
```

Thanks in advanced :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a customized path for your log file, so selinux is blocking you.
Try to issue `setenforce 0` and to restart rsyslog. If it now work, it is confirmed that your problem was selinux.

To permanently correct that while continue to use selinux, you need to issue

`semanage fcontext -a -t var_log_t '/opt/rsyslog(/.*)?'; restorecon -RF /opt/rsyslog`

After that, restart rsyslog.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have done the trick. Looks like its time to brush up on SELinux, any recommendations on reading material?